# Wordwrap within css div

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

I am having issues with wordwrapping within my div container. Here is the code for this specific section of code. I want it to automatically wrap to next line even if there are no spaces in the specified line of text.

```
#content {
    position: justify;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Times new roman;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Define how the text should wrap to next line. At some allowable break points (which?), with word hyphenation, or with strin gs brok en arbitra rily? What people usually offer as a solution means the last option, which is almost always wrong, though this depends on the content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [**`word-wrap:break-word`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5x5U/)

```
#content {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position:justify;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Times new roman;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your CSS

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```