# HTML/CSS Text will not follow div

Tags: html, css

The `<p>` tag that is located inside of a div will not break when reaching the max-width. I know some lines of code are not needed for anything but I don't even know anymore...

```
<body>

    <div id="bigBox">

        <div id="body">         
            <h1>Min profilsida</h1>

            <div id="navBar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ProfilSida.html">Hem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="CvSida.html">Cv</a></li>
                    <li><a href="PortfolioSida.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        <h2>Mitt namn är Albin Öhman</h2>

        <img src="bilder/Albiegrdn.png">    

        <div class="textbox">
            <p>fgodsfjklgdsflgjhhhhhhhhyukggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggyyygdsfdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
        </div>

        </div>


    </div>

</body>



 #body{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 850px;
    height: 790px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: #808080;
}


 .textbox{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 425px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    left: 350px;
    top: -450px;
}





   body{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#bigBox{
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #424747;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 810px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Whats your css look like? Have you tried adding a word-wrap property?

Comment: [word-wrap Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
p {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Or a more general property:

```
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Paragraphs won't break a non-spaced word, unless you tell it to:

```css
.textbox{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 425px;
    height: 500px;
}

p {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="textbox">
  <p>fgodsfjklgdsflgjhhhhhhhhyukggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggyyygdsfdsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "will not break when reached the max-width?" are you referring to the

content continuing on passed the width of the ? if so then try this post

[Wordwrap within css div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880043/wordwrap-within-css-div)

so basically what you need to do is to either make the horizontal overflow to be set as scroll so you can scroll left and right as needed or turn on the word_wrap so as soon as it hits the end of the width, it starts a new line.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't actually setting max width anywhere only width. Also it will not break if the text within it has no spaces. The string needs to be broken up for it to break at a given line space